Is it unsafe to use getline() in c to read from stdin?
I know that an incorrect use of scanf() to read user input can lead to undefined behavior and potentially security holes in a program. I've seen many people suggesting that is better to use fgets() instead of scanf(), but I know that getline() automatically realloc whenever the line you are trying to read is larger than the buffer.  The only case I can think about getline() being unsafe is when the user sends too long a string to stdin so it attempts to allocate more memory than the OS can. I'm a little bit confused about this.  Is that why people seem to prefer fgets() over getline() or it has nothing to do with it?
I haven't tried this in code.  I just want to hear what experienced people think about this.

Both getline(3) and malloc(3) make it clear that errno will be set to ENOMEM should it fail to allocate enough memory. (It is not clear if you will have lost input.)

@Dúthomhas Thanks for your answer, https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline, there does not say about ENOMEM errno, is that an untrusted site to read documentation about the c standard library? Or is that a different version of the implementation?

IDK the reason, but I stopped using linux.die.net ages ago. man7.org is up-to-date with POSIX standards and has always correct AFAIK. cppreference.com makes it clear that the C Standard does not require setting errno, so if you plan to compile on something other than Linux it may be an issue.

The die.net HTMLized man pages also have horrible formatting compared to the man7 ones.

It depends on undelying OS and its settings. More likely process will be killed by OOM killer instead of returning ENOMEM.

cheto59, "... people seems to prefer fgets over getline() ..." --> fgets() is part of the C standard library.  getline() is not.

Note that no version of the C standard defines the getline() function.  It is defined in the official Technical Report — ISO/IEC TR 24731-2:2010 — the last draft of which was n1388.pdf.  However, that report was not included in C11, C18 or C23 (unlike TR 23731-1, which was included in C11 as Annex K).  The draft also says discrepancies with POSIX are unintentional and are resolved by using the POSIX definition ("This technical report defers to POSIX").

For most purposes, it is safe enough to use getline() to read standard input.  If you think that someone might supply your code with something like a multi-gigabyte JSON document formatted as a single line and your system might not provide enough memory, then it is not safe to use it.  It isn't very clearly specified what happens if memory allocation fails.  If the input data won't contain null bytes, using fgets() and allocating extra memory yourself as necessary will work.  If the data can contain null bytes, you can't tell what fgets() read.
